# Git - find a bug in specified commit

Tags: git, branch, git-commit, git-checkout

There is a bug appeared in commit **63aeeab**.
There are too many changes between **b947052** and **63aeeab**.
I want somehow checkout **63aeeab** and then discard changes one by one to find the bug. And then go back to my current commit. What is a proper way?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to checkout **63aeeab** and then reset to the previous commit. In this way you return as in **b947052** just before creating the next commit and all the changes introduced by 63aeeab will be in your working copy.

```
git checkout 63aeeab
git reset HEAD^
```

Note that these commands have no effects on the git tree shape, no branches are moved, no commits changed.

In this state you should be able to discard changes one by one (it could be helpful the `--patch` option of [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))

Let me say, sorry I have to do this, make small commits, add unit tests.